# Preview de foto erróneo

Tags: java, imagen

Tengo un problema y necesito ayuda pro.

Tengo un proyecto que sirve para gestiona gastos de empresas. Los gastos utilizan notas para representar la información, y además incluye una foto. El problema que ha surgido es que las fotos que aparecen son incorrectas, aparecen fotos de otras capturas anteriores. Aparentemente, las fotos se descargan correctamente y así mismo, el nombre que las identifica también es correcto. He comprobado la ruta de almacenamiento de fotos en el servidor, y el contenido es también correcto, ni rastro de las otras fotos.

Deduzco que es un tema de caché o de previews de fotos anteriores que crean conflictos. He leído que si las pruebas se realizan en el emulador, se pueden dar fallos de este tipo. Pero lo he probado en terminales, instalando y borrando toda la información, y me sigue pasando.

He encontrado algo que puede solucionar el problema utilizando: imagePipeline.evictFromCache

Me gustaría tener mas información, porque es un tema muy desconcertante.

Si alguien ha sufrido el mismo problema y ha encontrado una solución, le agradecería que lo compartiera conmigo.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Te recomiendo que te ganes la medalla por leer el [tour] y entender que es un [mcve]. La pregunta no aporta suficientes detalles para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que tratas, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por las contestaciones, y perdón por no aportar suficientes datos.
Al final, un compañero mío ha encontrado la solución.

Efectivamente, era un tema de caché. Como es una situación que se puede dar, os explico cómo se ha solucionado.

La situación es la que explico en el anunciado. Damos por sentado dos cosas: que la API funciona bien, es decir, que recibe y guarda bien la foto nueva. Y también, cuando lo necesitamos descargamos la foto correcta, pero no muestra la que debería. Dicho esto, sabemos que el problema está sólo en la app.

Android tiene un mecanismo de ahorro de datos, que consiste en descargar las fotos y guardaras con un nombre para no tener que descargarlas de nuevo más adelante. Cuando se descarga la nueva foto con el mismo nombre, Android interpreta que dicha foto ya la tenemos guardada, y por tanto no la descarga de nuevo, y muestra la foto antigua guardada.

Así que para solucionarlo, utilizamos unas utilidades de la librería Fresco (que es la que estamos utilizando para todo), para borrar cualquier dato relacionado con la foto. De este modo, siempre se descarga la foto independientemente del nombre.

Luego para optimizar la lógica, hay que distinguir las fotos modificadas, de las no modificadas, pero esto ya es otro tema.

Espero que ayude! Gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora repasando mis posts, aprovecho para dejar el código que arregla el problema, ya que nunca se sabe quien quede necesitarlo.

**La librería a importar:**

implementation('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.5.0')

**Crear el objeto:**

private ImagePipeline imagePipeline;

**Inicializar plugin Fresco (1 vez) al iniciar la app:**

Fresco.initialize(this);

**Inicializar en cada actividad que se necesite configurar la caché:**

imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline();

**Configurar de esta manera:**

```
        imagePipeline.evictFromMemoryCache(imgUri);
        imagePipeline.evictFromDiskCache(imgUri);
        imagePipeline.evictFromCache(imgUri);
        img.setImageURI(imgUri);
```

Siempre poner en la última linea, las operaciones que realizamos con las imágenes, para que pipeline pueda actuar debidamente.